# missing standard linq query operator?

Tags: linq

Is there a linq operator 'x' that does the following:

(1,2,3) 'x' (4,5,6) = ((1,4),(2,5),(3,6))

Geez and I can't remember the standard functional programming name either..

Comment: Kind of like transposing rows of a matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 4.0, [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) takes two `IEnumerable` and a function to combine an element from each into a single result. It emits an `IEnumerable` of the results.

In your example you would use `(a, b) => new Tuple<int, int>(a, b)` as the combining function.